# Google Spreadsheet refer cell to left and compare left cell with multiple cells

Tags: google-sheets

I can refer a cell to the left and compare it with one cell but i can not with multiply cells, the error is wrong number of arguments to IF expected 2 or 3 arguments, but I got 1 arguments

this works when I **compare the cell to the left to one cell**:

```
=IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS( ROW(),COLUMN()-1))=B3,C3)
```

this does not work when I **compare the cell to the left to multiple cells**:

```
=IF(or(INDIRECT(ADDRESS( ROW(),COLUMN()-1))=B3,C3),IF(or(INDIRECT(ADDRESS( ROW(),COLUMN()-1))=B4,C4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS( ROW(),COLUMN()-1))=B3, C3, IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS( ROW(),COLUMN()-1))=B4, C4,) )
```

Or alternatively:

```
=IFERROR(vlookup(INDIRECT(ADDRESS( ROW(),COLUMN()-1)), {B3,C3; B4,C4}, 2, 0))
```

The latter has the advantage of being easier to extent..